# how to write if with laravel blade on HTML div class

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

```
  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">
   @foreach($product as $item)
   <!-- if id of item is one set to active if not to empty -->
   <div class="item {{$item['id']== 1?'active':''}}">
      <img src="la.jpg" alt="Chania">
      <div class="carousel-caption ">
        <h3>Los Angeles</h3>
        <p>LA is always so much fun!</p>
      </div>
      
   @endforeach
    </div>
```

i have wirte the if conditoin but it dos not worked I want to show the first slide as active

Comment: For debugging, did you print out `$item['id']`? Does it exist? Is it 1? Or is it `$item->id`?

Comment: fyi, you're missing a closing `</div>` in your `@foreach`

Comment: *"but it dos not worked"* - This statement is not helpful... _Why_ isn't it working? What error (if any) did you get when using this code? Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75917345/edit) and provide more details, and be sure to better explain your problems in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">
   @foreach($product as $item)
   <!-- if id of item is one set to active if not to empty -->
   <div class="item {{$item->id == 1 ? 'active': ''}}"> <!-- your id rendering caused it -->
      <img src="la.jpg" alt="Chania">
      <div class="carousel-caption ">
        <h3>Los Angeles</h3>
        <p>LA is always so much fun!</p>
      </div>
      </div>  <!-- closing div is needed as well -->
   @endforeach
</div>
```

Comment: How do you know it's `$item->id` and not `$item['id']`? What if OP passed an array to the view?

Comment: That's the way i understand how laravel renders the item in the array. I'm not fortunate to see how the data were queried in the controller, but since he used `$item['id']` and didnt work, the next option is `$item->id`

Comment: In Laravel, there are cases where `$item->id` **OR** `$item['id']` are interchangeable, such as a typical Model query: `$product = Product::all()`, then `foreach($product as $item)`. On the other hand, if Models aren't being used, like `$product = DB::table('products')->get()`, then `$item['id']` will trigger an error, and you have to use `$item->id` (`DB::table()->get()` returns a `Collection` of `stdClass` Objects, which need `->`, while Models are flexible). Brombeer is correct though, this is a guess at best, and turned out to be correct, but the question needed more detail *first*.